# What kind of message will the Windows OS process when I press a key like '1' for several seconds?

Tags: windows, keyboard, message-queue

There is no WM_KEYPRESS message in winuser.h. The OS will process the message WM_KEYDOWN all the time? Or some other message type?

Comment: It is called WM_CHAR.  The repeat behavior you get by holding down the key is implemented by the keyboard, not the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/gg153546(v=vs.85).aspx

If you hold down a key long enough to start the keyboard's repeat feature, the system sends multiple key-down messages, followed by a single key-up message.